# Using Thrust library of CUDA for large values

Tags: matlab, thrust

Hi I wanted to implement a loop which is extremely large in thrust but i find it much slower than normal C++ code. Can you please tell me where am i going wrong.
fi and fj are host vectors

xsize usually is around a 7-8 digit number

```
thrust::host_vector <double> df((2*floor(r)*(floor(r)+1)+1)*n*n); 
thrust::device_vector<double> gpu_df((2*floor(r)*(floor(r)+1)+1)*n*n); 
     for(i=0;i<xsize;i++)
     {
        gpu_df[i]=(fi[i]-fj[i]);

         if(gpu_df[i]<0)
            gpu_df[i]=0;
        else 
       gpu_df[i]=gpu_df[i]*(fi[i]-fj[i]);
        if(gpu_df[i]>255)
            gpu_df[i]=255;
        //      cout<<fi[i]<<"\n";
     }
df=gpu_df;
```

I feel the code is not being parallelized. Could you please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run programs on the GPU with Thrust you need to write them in terms of Thrust algorithms like `reduce`, `transform`, `sort`, etc.  In this case we can write the computation in terms of `transform`, since the loop was just computing a function `F(fi[i], fj[i])` and storing the result in `df[i]`.  Note that we must first move the input arrays to the device before calling `transform` because Thrust requires the input and output arrays to live in the same place.

```
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/functional.h>
#include <cstdio>

struct my_functor
  : public thrust::binary_function<float,float,float>
{
  __host__ __device__
  float operator()(float fi, float fj)
      {
    float d =  fi - fj;

    if (d < 0)
      d = 0;
    else
      d = d * d;

    if (d > 255)
      d = 255;

    return d;
  }
};

int main(void)
{
  size_t N = 5;

  // allocate storage on host
  thrust::host_vector<float>   cpu_fi(N);
  thrust::host_vector<float>   cpu_fj(N);
  thrust::host_vector<float>   cpu_df(N);

  // initialze fi and fj arrays
  cpu_fi[0] = 2.0;  cpu_fj[0] =  0.0;
  cpu_fi[1] = 0.0;  cpu_fj[1] =  2.0;
  cpu_fi[2] = 3.0;  cpu_fj[2] =  1.0;
  cpu_fi[3] = 4.0;  cpu_fj[3] =  5.0;
  cpu_fi[4] = 8.0;  cpu_fj[4] = -8.0;

  // copy fi and fj to device
  thrust::device_vector<float> gpu_fi = cpu_fi;
  thrust::device_vector<float> gpu_fj = cpu_fj;

  // allocate storage for df
  thrust::device_vector<float> gpu_df(N);

  // perform transformation
  thrust::transform(gpu_fi.begin(), gpu_fi.end(),  // first input range
                    gpu_fj.begin(),                // second input range
                    gpu_df.begin(),                // output range
                    my_functor());                 // functor to apply

  // copy results back to host
  thrust::copy(gpu_df.begin(), gpu_df.end(), cpu_df.begin());

  // print results on host
  for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
    printf("f(%2.0lf,%2.0lf) = %3.0lf\n", cpu_fi[i], cpu_fj[i], cpu_df[i]);

  return 0;
}
```

For reference, here's the output of the program:

```
f( 2, 0) =   4
f( 0, 2) =   0
f( 3, 1) =   4
f( 4, 5) =   0
f( 8,-8) = 255
```

Comment: Thank you wnbell. Is it possible for 2d vectors as well. I want something like xi[i][0]-xj[i][0] so will it be like xi[0]-xj[0]?

Comment: Thrust only provides a one-dimensional vector container, so you'd have to decide how to flatten the 2d vector into a 1d vector.  Assuming you flatten all 2d vectors the same way, you can often ignore the 2d nature of the data when calling algorithms like ``transform``.